# CSS <a> tag states are changing color en mass, i.e. a click on one link changes ALL links to 'visited' color -- any ideas?

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink, css-selectors

Styles were created in the correct order.  Also tried pseudo-classes, which have always worked for me before. Tried differnt locations in the css list. Tried all link CSS in a separate file. 
I don't have a problem creating the styles.  Just not working correctly.  Have stripped it down and rebuit a number of times.  The All Links color change happened with all set of pseudo-classes as well as CSS base links.  A click on a 'normal' link of changed all the links on the page.  Sorry if I'm rambling -- 21 hours straight trying to fix it.  Alternating with more fun stuff, of course.

Comment: Are all links to the same URL perhaps? The "visited" property is attached to the destination URL, not a specific anchor.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Firebug or Google Chrome's dev tools to view the css styles applied to your anchor tags.  This will indicate where you are getting the unexpected style.  If you have never done this before download Google Chrome using the link below.  After you install, Click the Wrench icon -> Tools -> Developer Tools.  This will pop up the tools at the bottom of the window.  I'd suggest using the magnifying glass (left of the "html" tag at bottom left corner) and just look at each anchor tag, before and after you click to see how the styles change.  This can then lead you to determining where or how your unexpected styles are coming from.

http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome.html?hl=en

Good luck!

Matti